# VBA SystemTime - 30 days

Tags: ms-access, vba, systemtime

I am working on a code from a previous developer. This code has SystemTime set up. 
Is there a way to get today date and minus 30 days in this format?

Code Below:

```
Public Function GetIsoTimestampTest() As String
Dim st As SYSTEMTIME

'Get the local date and time
GetSystemTime st

'Format the result
GetIsoTimestampTest = _
    Format$(st.wYear, "0000") & "-" & _
    Format$(st.wMonth, "00") & "-" & _
    Format$(st.wDay, "00") & "T" & _
    Format$(st.wHour, "00") & ":" & _
    Format$(st.wMinute, "00") & ":" & _
    Format$(st.wSecond, "00") & "Z"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a native date & time, add -30 days, format as a string:

```
utcInIsoFormat = Format$(DateAdd("d", -30, _
    DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay) _
    + TimeSerial(st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond)), "yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ssZ")
```

Answer (score 0):

SYSTEMTIME appears to be a custom type defined elsewhere in your code.  It's not a standard type available in Access VBA.  So to use it effectively, you need to find the definition.  Also GetSystemTime is also likely a custom function exclusive to your code.  Here's a sample definition of a similar type, although it may not be exactly what's implemented in your system: http://custom-designed-databases.com/wordpress/2011/get-milliseconds-or-seconds-from-system-time-with-vba/

That said, System Time would refer to the Windows system time.  You also have a native ability in VBA to get time using the Now() function.  (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278671.aspx)  This returns a variable with type Date, which is equivalent to a number where the integer represents days and the decimal represents time of day.  An example to get 30 days prior to today would be:

```
Dim lastMonth as Date
Dim formattedDate as String    

lastMonth = Now() - 30
formattedDate = Format(lastMonth, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:nn:ssZ")
```

Comment: GetSystemTime() is a platform API, it returns the current time in UTC.

Comment: But it's not available in Access VBA natively.  You have to create a function to access it the way the OP describes.

Comment: Well you only have to declare it, point was it returns UTC time unlike Now() which is local time.

Answer (score 0):

DateSerial happily accepts a negative day count. Thus:

```
Public Function IsoDateMinus30() As Date

    Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim Result As Date

    ' Get the local date and time
    GetSystemTime st

    Result = DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay - 30)

    ' To include time:
    '
    ' Result = _
    '     DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay - 30) + _
    '     TimeSerial(st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond)    

    IsoDateMinus30 = Result

End Function
```